# Determining whether a point is inside an Oriented Bounding Box

Tags: algorithm, rust, geometry, game-physics, game-development

I know this question has been asked a lot of times in various places. I've looked at many of them to try and figure out why my code is not doing what I expect, and I am at a complete loss!

I'm trying to determine whether the point under the mouse cursor in world coordinates is within a rotated quad using the Oriented Bounding Box technique. This works for the non-rotated quads (the blue square) but when rotation is applied (yellow rectangle) it fails - some points in the rectangle are not computed as being contained and some outside the rectangle are computed as being contained. The origin for rotation is currently the bottom left corner (but I plan to be able to specify where the origin is at a later date).

[image: Example of rotated rects]

I understand that I can transform the point into the rectangles local coordinate space by applying the inverse of the rectangles transform to the point. However, this is not doing what I'd expect, as described above, even after implementing the changes suggested in the comments below:

```rust
for (id, (transform,)) in game.world.query::<(&Transform,)>().iter() {
    let inverse = compute_inverse_transformation_matrix(transform);

    let test_point = (inverse * Vec4::from((state.mouse_world_pos, 0.0, 0.0))).xy();

    if test_point.x >= transform.position.x
        && test_point.x <= transform.position.x + transform.size.x
        && test_point.y >= transform.position.y
        && test_point.y <= transform.position.y + transform.size.y
    {
        state.active_entity = Some(id);
    }
}

...

pub fn compute_transformation_matrix(t: &Transform) -> Mat4 {
    Mat4::from_scale_rotation_translation(
        Vec3::from((t.size, 0.0)),
        Quat::from_rotation_z(-t.rotation.to_radians()),
        Vec3::from((t.position, 0.0)),
    )
}

pub fn compute_inverse_transformation_matrix(t: &Transform) -> Mat4 {
    Mat4::from_scale_rotation_translation(
        Vec3::from((1.0 / t.size, 0.0)),
        Quat::from_rotation_z(t.rotation.to_radians()),
        Vec3::from((-t.position, 0.0)),
    )
}
```

How can I check whether the world coordinate represented by the mouse cursor position is bounded by a rotated rectangle?

Comment: Your basic idea to transform the screen point to a space where the box is axis-aligned is okay, but the inverse transformation may not be correct. If you apply `inverse` to the four corners of the rectangle, do you get the desired axis-aligned box?

Comment: I’ll have to do a bit of refactoring to check that out. Currently, the only place where I know the actual coordinates of the rectangle are for the vertices when I render it, after applying the transformation matrix to a 1.0x1.0 square.

Comment: In that case, you should also test your transformed mouse coordinates against a 1×1 square. If your `inverse` reverses all the steps from the original to the transformed rect, the inversely-transformed coords should be inside the original rect.

Comment: [I'm also not sure  whether your inverse matrix is correct. If your transformation from a 1×1 square with its lower left point in the origin is: scale(ax, ay); then rotate(θ); then translate(dx, dy), your inverse transformation is translate(−dx, −dy); then rotate(−θ); then scale(1 / ax, 1 / ay). Then thest whether 0 < x′ < 1 and 0 < y′ < 1.]

Comment: It would seem my inverse transformation matrix is incorrect for the rotated quad, as it does not get me back to the original 1x1 square, even after those changes:

`Large Rect
Transform [Vec2(0.0, -0.0), Vec2(-401.48746, -860.9924), Vec2(280.9554, -131.0117), Vec2(-120.53204, -992.0041)]
Inverse [Vec2(0.0, 0.0), Vec2(2.6957808, 0.79075575), Vec2(0.2580361, 0.44664004), Vec2(2.953817, 1.2373959)]
Small Square
Transform [Vec2(0.0, 0.0), Vec2(100.0, 0.0), Vec2(0.0, 100.0), Vec2(100.0, 100.0)]
Inverse [Vec2(0.0, 0.0), Vec2(1.0, 0.0), Vec2(0.0, 1.0), Vec2(1.0, 1.0)]`

Comment: I think the scale factors, offsets and angles in your transformations are right, but the order of the transformations ia also important, becaue matrix multiplication is not associative like multiplication of scalars. So if you scale, rotate, translate to get there, you must translate back, rotate back and scale back to get the original.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're totally right about the non-associativeness. Even with that change, the bounds checking is still off, but getting better. The inverse of the rotated rect now comes out as e.g. `[Vec2(0.0, 0.0), Vec2(1.0, -1.1920929e-7), Vec2(0.0, 0.99999994), Vec2(1.0, 0.9999998)]`, which I assume is floating point error. Is that sufficient enough to now be the cause of the problems?

Comment: Yes, that looks like rounding errors owed to repeated matrix multiplication. If you apply the same inverse transformation to the mouse point and test against the unit square, your hit test should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245090/discussion-between-amb85-and-m-oehm).

Comment: Finally found it - `let test_point = (inverse * Vec4::from((state.mouse_world_pos, 0.0, 0.0))).xy();`. `w` coord should have been set to 1.0, not 0.0!!! Thanks again for your help :-D

Comment: Ha, so it was the translation, not the rotation after all. (There's a "Lost in Translation" pun lurking somewhere, I guess.) Good you found it!